# log with log4j configuration not work

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, configuration, log4j2

i have this configuration in my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="FileLogger" fileName="HelloLog4j.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="hello" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="FileLogger"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

i put this file in src/resources, and i follow this guide: [Guide](http://syncor.blogspot.it/2013/09/getting-started-with-log4j-2-in-eclipse.html)
but when i run my project i have this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487116/log4j2-configuration-no-log4j2-configuration-file-found

Comment: is possible dup but my problem is i have this file in my classpath..but not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML file has to be inside the `src` folder itself and not inside `src/resources` or anything inside it, it has to be at root level of the folder.However if that does not work out here is a slightly different way of doing it.

You can use [DOM Configurator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html) to configure the logger manually.

Below is a sample snippet which describers how you can use it.

```
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger;

public static Logger getLogger(){
    if(logger == null){
        logger= LogManager.getLogger(ClassName.class);
        DOMConfigurator.configure("path/to/log4jxml");
    }
    return logger;

}
```

Class name would be the class in which you are instantiating the class.It is good practice to use Singleton design pattern for this in a custom class and then instantiating it via the getLogger method.Don't forget to make your constructor private.

**Edit:**

A sample config for console appender.The conversion pattern is date layout.

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

Comment: but in web.xml i must add something?

Comment: This is not related to web.xml.First try to place the log4j2.xml in the src root itself.If that does not work out, then try to use the code that I gave to instantiate the Logger instance.But, this would differ if you are using a build tool such as Maven or something, but either way the code should work.

Comment: the configuration now work, but does not print anything...i try  logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
      logger.info("Hello world - info log");
      logger.warn("Hello world - warn log");

Comment: Try to call logger.info from the same class from which you created, just to test it out.Now since the classpath issue is resolved, try different configuration files, I have added a sample configuration,check it out.

Comment: but this DOMConfiguration isn't for log4j 2?

Comment: The config is Log4j style (older version) but a working example from which I am using, so that you can verify your config.You can refer [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the use of DOMConfigurator, stick to the standard: put log4j2.xml in your classpath. Where that is depends on your app and your runtime environment.