# Adding a system property for Launch4j in Maven (using Log4j 2)

Tags: java, maven, log4j2, launch4j

As logging-tool I am using Log4j2 and this is invoked by using a system property (/VM argument), using:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./config/log4j2_config.xml
```

For compiling my projects I am using Maven and to create exe-files Launch4j (Plugin: com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j).

The plugin definition in my pom.xml looks like that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>l4j-clui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                <cmdLine>./config/MyConfig.xml</cmdLine>
                <opt>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.configurationFile=./config/log4j2_config.xml</opt>
                <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                <outfile>${project.build.directory}/MyExe.exe</outfile>
                <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                <classPath>
                    <mainClass>de.my.path.MainClass</mainClass>
                    <!-- <preCp>anything</preCp> -->
                </classPath>
                <!-- <icon>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/application.ico</icon> -->
                <jre>
                    <minVersion>1.7.0_00</minVersion>
                    <!-- <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference> -->
                </jre>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My question is now:

How can I set the system property for the log4j2 integration?!

If tried to put it in brackets with "opt" (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

or something like that:

```
                        <vars>
                            <var>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./config/log4j2_config.xml</var>
                        </vars>
```

But both did not work and my logger wasn't logging..

Maybe you had the same problem and can help me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with launch4j or the maven plugin, but [according to the Ant docs](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html), you specify System Properties with `<opt>` tags.  And the maven plugin docs say that the pom structure is similar, so did you try using `<opt>` tags **inside the `<jre>` tags?**

like

```
    <jre>
        <opt>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./config/log4j2_config.xml</opt>
    </jre>
```

Try that, and let me know if it works.

Now a question:

Is there a reason that you are using a different name for your config? Normally the filename is `log4j2.xml`. If you use that name, the config should automatically be loaded and you don`t need the system property.

Comment: Hey! the first opportunity didn't work.. Rename the file in <code>log4j2.xml</code> and put it in the src folder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487116/log4j2-configuration-no-log4j2-configuration-file-found) worked!! For now, I've written the author of the plugin, because the opportunity to add system propoerties should be possible and is a little bit nicer solution, in my opinion.. ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<opts>
    <opt>-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml</opt>
</opts>
```