# Maven - ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

When running `mvn verify` I am getting below message:

[image]

I already put the `log4j2.xml` under `src/test/resources` (but not in `src/main/resources` because I do not want it to ship with actual app) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25487455) to no avail.

[image]

The HTML report is generated, the log file is written, and the build is successful as seen above. I am unsure where the error is coming from.

Comment: Is it the same message if you add the following dependency in the pom -> <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @MrCas Still the same error message after adding `log4j-api`. After all, it is a transient dependency of `log4j-core` so it shouldn't matter whether it's specified in the pom.xml or not.

Comment: have you tried `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///path/to/your/log4j2.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration adding `log4j2.xml` to classpath should help.

> If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try
>   to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.

So if you still get ERROR message problem not with your sources. It looks like problem in `maven-cucumber-reporting` plugin. As described here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html

> Please note that the plugin classloader does neither contain the dependencies of the current project nor its build output.

If maven plugin cannot find any log4j configuration in its own classpath (which is not including your sources/resources) you will see error messages. So yes, the only solution wait for release with fix https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/675

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this bounty but this is impressive detective work. Acceptable explanation and marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You use the latest Cucumber version 3.15.0 (at the time of writing this). Your problem was resolved as [issue #675](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/675). There was a [commit](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/commit/195347fe0c1b374c9630c130f6fd111ac334bc49) from a [pull request](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/pull/712) meant to fix this problem, but probably you have to wait until the next version is released in order to profit from it - or build a snapshot version locally and see if it also fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Well, you can un-accept the other one and accept mine. My answer has been written 4 days before the accepted one and is correct. The other answer does not add value and even points to the very same ticket mine pointed to before. First come, first serve.

Answer (score 1):

Run -> Run Configurations -> Classpath -> User entries -> Advanced Optiones -> Add Folders -> Then add your folder,in your case src/test/resources -> apply

It must work now :D

Comment: Thank you but the src/test/resources is already marked as a source folder. Everything in it already goes to the target classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because `cucumber` or its dependencies are using `log4j` for logging and since there is no `log4j` configuration file so `log4j` is printing such message.

If there is no `log4j` configuration file, `log4j` uses configuration similar to below  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configuration>

<Configuration status="warn" name="xml_configuration">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%level] %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="consoleLogger" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Adding above configuration in `/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` will have same result as having no `log4j2.xml` file.

Another way to try is to pass `log4j2.xml` file to maven directly without putting it in project classpath. Something like below -

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///path/to/log4j2.xml"
mvn verify
```

Comment: Hi, I do have the config file in the classpath. Turns out, this was a known defect in the `maven-cucumber-reporting` plugin itself that was not fixed until recently.

Answer (score 0):

according to their documentation, you can use 'joranConfigurator' and load the configuration from a specified file

[documentation link](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly)

Comment: Thank you but this is a different logging framework.