# Not able to write logs using RollingFileAppender in log4j2

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I am doing a Simple demo project in Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat
I am accepting JSON request from Postman and providing JSON response .
Now i also want to do logging in my project .

So i have use log4j2
**Jars used** :-
 log4j-1.2.12.jar ,
 jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar ,
 jackson-core-2.6.3.jar

Servlet Code :-

```
@WebServlet("/StatusServlet")
public class TestingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestingServlet.class);

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        String requestData = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(requestData);

        // 2. initiate jackson mapper

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            TestingPojo pojo = mapper.readValue(requestData, TestingPojo.class);

           logger.info("status "+pojo.getStatus());
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            mapper.writeValue(out, pojo.getStatus());
            out.flush(); 


    }
```

My Project Directory :-

```
Webservice            
   |-src         
      |- com       
          |-test          
             TestingPojo.java               
             TestingServlet.java       
             log4j2.xml
```

My log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="TRACE">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logPath">/tmp</Property>
        <!-- <Property name="patternInfo">%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %F : %C 
            : %M() : THREAD[%t] : LINE[%L] : [%m]%n</Property> -->
        <Property name="patternInfo">%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${logPath}/i-am.log"
            filePattern="${logPath}/webservice-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${patternInfo}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10 MB"/> -->
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When i run the code in eclipse i get logs in console in pattern format .
But when i deploy the code in remote server i get no logs in mentioned Rolling File Appender path . No file gets created.

Is there anything wrong with my configurations ?
Also I have used Basic Configurator.configure() , Is there any other way ?

Comment: I don't know about Tomcat but for most servers the logging configuration is centralized so every application doesn't have to configure its own log files

Answer (score 0):

I found same article for you.(You need to change directory for log4j2.xml)

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487116/log4j2-configuration-no-log4j2-configuration-file-found)!

There are two way explained,

1. placed log4j2.xml in class path(recommand)
2. run tomcat with logging jvm option

This is out of OP's question, but I hope you remind this.

- Please consider to add console Appender, it would be nice to see in your IDE console.
- Please consider re-use ObjectMapper : 
  [Jackson-Performance](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance) , 
  [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)