# Unable to start hive due to no log4j2 configuration file found

Tags: hive, log4j2, derby

I am trying to setup hive in Windows 11 machine. However, unable to establish connection with hive : -
[image]

Root cause of the problem is there is no "hive-log4j2.properties".

I had downloaded the binaries from here https://archive.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.1.0/

However, I see some videos in youtube this file was earlier present https://youtu.be/BV1FgKYjc8E

Do any of you have any suggestion how to get this file and setup hive properly.

Comment: This is exclusively related to hive set up.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: [Log4j2 configuration - No log4j2 configuration file found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487116/log4j2-configuration-no-log4j2-configuration-file-found?rq=2)

It seems the same error. You may need to add the log4j xml configuration file manually.

Comment: This solution doesn't satisfy my requirement. I am configuring hive in my windows machine. I miss .xml and properties file. Do anyone have them handy and pass it to me.